# Subjunctive mood (or not): If my girlfriend go/goes

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I have been reading up on subjunctive mood, but I am having trouble seeing why this sentence is incorrect:

"If my girlfriend go to bed, I will play with you."

Here it is conditional, so could someone please explain to me, why the verb should be 'goes' and not 'go'? Thank you.

Comment: There are many types of conditional sentences in English. You really should do your own research before asking a question here. Also, you should consider asking on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Simce I do not find your question worthy of an answer, I'll just *comment* that your sentence is a **real conditional** and this type of conditional sentence does not entail the subjuntive. You can begin your research by searching the internet for real conditionals and unreal conditionals in English.

Comment: How many girlfriends do you have?  OK, ignoring that, how many girlfriends are you referring to when you say "girlfriend"?

Comment: I didn't know that on a website which is made for asking questions that one is not allowed to ask a question - merely because the question seems too simple or basic to what seems to be only one person. Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wikipedia: The English subjunctives occurs 'in if clauses expressing a condition that does not or did not hold ("If she were here right now, ..."; "If she had been here yesterday, ...")'.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood

In your example it is very possible that the girlfriend will go to bed. It is sometimes called the first conditional and is *not* in the subjunctive mood: if my girlfriend goes to bed, I will play with you.

The so-called 2nd and 3rd conditionals of your example would be formulated with a subjunctive:

2nd conditional: If my girlfriend went to bed, I would play with you.

3rd conditional: If my girlfriend had  gone to bed, I would have played with you.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries [provides](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive) a far better synopsis of the subjunctive. That Wikipedia link is an annoying wall of text.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's a much clearer text, though I thought the Wiki quote relevant to this particular question (and figured since I quoted it, I should give the link too).

Answer (score 0):

The subjunctive mood has nothing to do with why your example sentence is incorrect. The simple reason is that *girlfriend go* is an invalid verb conjugation in this context.

(It puts me in mind of the syntax used by the Marvel character Hulk. While he can get away with saying "Hulk smash," it's probably because nobody wants to correct him . . .)

If you want to specifically maintain the use of *go* (rather than changing it to *goes*) *and* use the subjunctive mood you need to make a few modifications:

> If my girlfriend **were to** go to bed, I **would** play with you.

Comment: "Go" here is wrong, yes, but that word is in fact the 3rd person singular subjunctive of the verb. (https://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctive.html)

Comment: @Wordster *Go* is not wrong if the changes I suggested are made. It gets to be kept and the sentence continues to be in a conditional form.

Comment: Yah, @Jason, I meant "go" in the original question.

Comment: "girlfriend go" is an invalid verb conjugation? "I prefer that my girlfriend go in my car" is invalid?

Comment: @Zebrafish You're right, of course. I had meant in the context of the example sentence, and have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

In Conditional Type One, also known as possible conditional, which is used when you want to talk about a possible event in the future, the if clause structure is Simple Present, and will + main verb comes afterward. For example :

If it rains tomorrow,  we'll have to stay home. (The speaker feels it's going to rain)

If she gets the job, she won't have to babysit any more.